# Having trouble making Views treat external content as nodes/entities

Tags: views

I have created a module by customizing [FlyViews](https://github.com/balintk/Session-FlyViews-Site-profile/tree/master/modules/custom/drupalcons) module to fetch data from a third party API and render via a **View**. I have been successful in showing the data on a page but the data has merely one style, that is, **fields**. Now I want to render that content as nodes of a specific content type. That content type will be configured in the module's configuration page. Once I mention a content type, the content should be rendered as nodes of that type.

Even a hardcoded solution will work for me, but it would be nice if I could select the **Show** option (on Views configuration page) as **Content**, just as I can do for a regular View.

**Edit**

I have implemented the custom row plugin which is now visible in Views UI as **Show** option under **Format**. Selecting the option and saving shows the output from my plugin's `render()` method. This is as far as I could get without help. Any ideas how can I manipulate `render()` to actually render the external content as nodes/entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally did it!

To achieve the result mentioned in the question, one can do the following:

1. Create a module implementing Views `row` plugin. To do so,

   1. Implement `hook_views_plugins()` mentioning your `row` plugin. For help, see [hook_views_plugins()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_plugins/7) documentation and its implementation in Views core class [views_views_plugins](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!plugins.inc/function/views_views_plugins/7).
   2. Implement the `row` plugin handler class. Create just a prototype for now.
   3. Mention the `row` plugin handler class in `module.info` file.
2. In your plugin handler class,

   1. override `option_definition()` and `options_form()` methods to present the user with a text field to input node id of the node to clone. You may use `entity_autocomplete` field for the purpose. (*If you wish to ask for a content type instead, you can use a content type drop down. I wish to use an existing node with tokens to replace with external content*). Overrid `validate()` method if you wish to validate the input. For help, see Views core class `views_plugin_row_node_view`.
   2. Overrid `render()` method to *load the node by id* or *create the node by content type*, build the node view using `node_view()` function, and return the rendered HTML using `drupal_render()` function. See `views_plugin_row_node_view::render()` for reference.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably not go down the the road of using Views (or Ctools) plugins at all here. (And I'm a big fan as well as proponent of Ctools and it's plugin architecture.)

I would create a new entity type, or a dummy content type of a node, and then take over the loading of said entity/content type with [hook_entity_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_load/7).

Why integrate with Views only, when you can integrate with Core instead, possibly even with less effort?

Comment: That way I would have to implement filter, sorting, pagination, etc. a lot of stuff which I can get from Views straight away!